# FullCalendar: change width of events

Tags: html, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I need to display 3 events and place them next to one another. Let's say There are 3 events at the same time. Actually they appear with same width of 33%. I am using extendedProps to apply different CSS style in render hooks (e.g. a different background color). I disabled slotEventOverlap.

Is there a way to change the width of the first event (in the first column) to e.g. 10% with, and the remaining two to 90%/2 = 45%?

I am using Fullcaleder v5 and I tried already to change the CSS left and right properties in the eventDidMount hook.

**UPDATE 1:**
I am using the timeGridWeek view. I am loading events from 3 different data sources. Events of source 1 will have type: "TypeA", events of source 2 will have "TypeB", etc. For each day I have events with 3 different types, which I am to order that way that events of TypeA are shown in the left column of a day, Events of TypeB in the middle and events of TypeC on the right:

[image]

What i try to achive is to modify the width of the events within the first column (the one that shows events of TypeA, in this case it will just be a bar without any title/text):

[image]

I ws trying to update the left and right property of the parent node of an element in the element that is passed through the eventDidMount function (because i noticed that the left/right attributes are in case of 3 events at the same time from 0..33%, 33%..66% and 66%..100%). So after loading the events i compute the left and right property for each day and event (for each day: give me events of TypeA, compute left and right, give me events of TypeB, compute left and right, etc.)

In the eventDidMount function i try to apply these left and right values:

```js
  eventDidMount: function (arg) {
    // make the first colum less width
    var type = arg.event.extendedProps.type;
    if (type === 'TypeA') {
      var node = arg.el.parentElement;

      // left,right will have a percentage value computed before, e.g. 0% and 10%
      var left = arg.event.extendedProps.force_left;
      var right = arg.event.extendedProps.force_right;
      node.style.setProperty("left", left);
      node.style.setProperty("right", right);
    }
  }
```

**UPDATE 2:**
The reason for disabling eventOverlap is because it looks better when having lots of events.

I set up an example on CodeSandbox which shows 3 types of events (3 data sources / stored in a database). I have the following scenario:

TypeB events are the planned one, TypeC events are the real times that someone will book and TypeA is kind of start and end summary (e.g. check in, check out). Now i am trying to render the TypeA events as a thin bar (title and times are not important) and the other events wider. I am able to change the width but the space for the event/column is reserved to 33%. And it should be not a global setting because there are days without events of TypeA (only TypeB or TypeC then).

Any help is appreciated:

https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-maxwell-g2kuu?file=/src/CalendarDemo.js

Comment: what exactly did you try in eventDidMount? What was the result? It would be really helpful if we could see some code and event data, to give us the tools to investigate. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the update. So, what was the result when you tried to apply this code? Can we see a demo (e.g. using the Snippets feature here, or on CodePen)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will prepare it. Actually it is not working (the attributes i am applying are ignored). The idea behind is to have some kind of thin bar (events of TypeA) for some days (not for all of them). This bar should indicate events for e.g. "Out of office", that come from a different data source. Next, events of TypeB are more detailed, e.g. Visiting Customer1, Visiting Customer2. Events of type B are coming from a different data source.

Comment: Ok thanks. BTW is there a specific reason why you don't want to use the slotEventOverlap feature?

Comment: Please see the example in the Update 2 section

Comment: Ah I see now from your demo, thanks. So it adjusts the widths, but it doesn't bunch them up on the left as you wanted. If you look at the event elements using your browser's element inspector you'll see this is because the events are using `position:absolute` - so they have a defined position on the page, not inside a flow, or relative to anything else. So they won't move up into empty space. That's set by fullCalendar's view rendering engine. Not much you can do about that, aside from forking the code for this view and creating your own custom version which has different rendering rules.

Comment: See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-js for more details of that approach - but it probably won't be simple, even with starting from the codebase of an existing view.

Comment: Thank you! I think implementing a csutom view is too hard.